# how to change content of external javascript with javascript

Tags: javascript, external-js

im working on a userscript for youtube, so i cant change the actual file on their server, but i need a way to change one of the functions in it.
the function seems to not exist before and after it runs.
i could probably change the URL of the file in the html, for example with:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace( /*javascript file URL before*/g, "*after*");
```

but im afraid the file is called from other places too, like somewhere in their obfuscated javascript i cant make out, so it would be better to not change its URL, but the code the page loads from it.
i dont know how though. is there maybe a way to listen to when a function is called from the file, and give a different code instead?

Answer (score 0):

Just override the javascript function like:

```
yourFunction = function(a){
  alert(a)
};
```

Comment: but the function isnt even created until it runs. so it would override my function. and it also seems to be deleted after it runs, since firebug returns the "not defined" error. the only way i could do that is if i could somehow overwrite the function right before its called